# TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable?

Tags: python, iterator

I am trying to do a hangman code in python 2.7 and I'm getting the **type error** around the line that says

> print char.

I'm sorry, I forgot to add the rest of the code. Here's the full code. Word is coming from a dictionary file.

```
import random
import string

WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def load_words():

    print "Loading word list from file..."
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
    # line: string
    line = inFile.readline()
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = string.split(line)
    print "  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded."
    return wordlist

def choose_word(wordlist):
    return random.choice(wordlist)

wordlist = load_words()
print "Welcome to Hangman where your wits will be tested!"
name = raw_input("Input your name: ")
print ("Alright, " + name + ", allow me to put you in your place.")
word = random.choice(wordlist)
print ("My word has ")
print len(word)
print ("letters in it.")

guesses = 10
failed = 0
for char in word:
        if char in guesses: 
            print char,
        else:
            print "_",
            failed += 1
            if failed == 0:
                print "You've Won. Good job!"
                break
            # 
            guess = raw_input("Alright," + name + ", hit me with your best guess.")
            guesses += guess
            if guess not in word:
                guesses -= 1
                print ("Wrong! I'm doubting your intelligence here," + name)
                print ("Now, there's only " + guesses + " guesses left until the game ends.")
                if guesses == 0:
                    print ("I win! I win! I hanged " + name + "!!!")
```

Comment: Iterables are collections by definition.  An `int` variable is not a collection; it is a single item.

Comment: What is `word`?  Is it iterable?

Comment: Whatever integer variable you are iterating over should be replaced with `range(integer_value)` instead of just `integer_value`. I think we need to see the last assignment of the variables used in your `for` loop.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: *"Iterables are collections by definition"*? Most collections do tend to be iterable, but the two concepts are quite distinct.

Comment: @NPE: I'm not a python expert, so I'm probably getting my terminology wrong.  My point is that the OP needs to think about what the error message is telling him.

Answer (score 1):

You try:

```
if char in guesses:
```

However, `guesses` is just the *count* of the number of guesses left, an integer, so you can't iterate over it. Perhaps you should also store the previous guesses and use that:

```
guess_list = []
...
if char in guess_list:
...
guess_list.append(guess)
```

For the same reason, if you got that far

```
guesses += guess
```

would fail - `guess` is a string and `guesses` an integer, which can't be added together.